# Unexpected nested loop behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a sort, and I've run into some unexpected behavior:

```
var searches = ['beta', 'alpha'];
var i = 0; j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < searches.length; i++){
        min = i;

        // first time through, i = 0
         alert(i); 
        for(j = i; j<searches.length; j++);
        {
            // first time through j = 2. If i = 0, how does j = 2?
             alert(j); 
            // .. sort code
        }
}
```

In fact, j is always 2. Why isn't j being set to i when it enters the for loop?

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2kK9/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a misplaced semi-colon:

```
for (j = i; j < searches.length; j++); // <--
```

The rest is interpreted as a block that runs *after* the loop has executed (when `j == 2`).

Take that out and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your nested for loop isn't doing anything:

```
for(j = i; j<searches.length; j++); // <- Your for loop proceeds only on this line.
```

Remove the semi colon.